# Generate migration - create join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, migration, join

I have looked through many `SO` and `google` posts for generating migration of join table for `has many and belongs to many` association and nothing work.

All of the solutions are generating a empty migration file.

I am using `rails 3.2.13` and I have two tables: `security_users` and `assignments`. These are some of things I have try:

```
rails generate migration assignments_security_users

rails generate migration create_assignments_security_users

rails generate migration create_assignments_security_users_join_table

rails g migration create_join_table :products, :categories (following the official documentation)

rails generate migration security_users_assignments security_user:belongs_to assignments:belongs_to
```

Can anyone tell how to create a join table migration between two tables?

Answer (score 202, accepted):

To autopopulate the create_join_table command in the command line, it should look like this:

```
rails g migration CreateJoinTableProductsSuppliers products suppliers
```

For a Product model and a Supplier model. Rails will create a table titled "products_suppliers".  Note the pluralization.

(Side note that `generation` command can be shortened to just `g`)

Comment: Take care when using CreateJoinTable because when dealing with tables with a prefix like my_products and my_suppliers, it will generate a join table like this my_products_my_suppliers while ActiveRecord expects it to be my_products_suppliers. Then associations like MyProduct.first.my_suppliers will not work! Check https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13683 - My solution was to keep using CreateJoinTable but add `table_name: :my_products_suppliers` in the migration http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Answer (score 47):

Run this command to generate the empty migration file (it is not automatically populated, you need to populate it yourself):

```
rails generate migration assignments_security_users
```

Open up the generated migration file and add this code:

```
class AssignmentsSecurityUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assignments_security_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :assignment_id
      t.integer :security_user_id
    end
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate` from your terminal.  I created [a quiz on many_to_many relationships](http://www.codequizzes.com/rails/learn-rails/many-to-many-relationships) with a simple example that might help you.

Comment: If you do it this way, make sure you add ```null: false``` to the field definitions. For example: ```t.integer :assignment_id, null: false```. This will protect against ghastly situations where you end up with a join table pointing nowhere, your data loses integrity and your code falls over. (Or ends up riddled with ugly and bug-prone guard code).

Comment: I concur with @Powers and would add that perhaps it's an idea to add a index to those columns?

Comment: With caveats, Rails can do more of the work for you than this answer suggests. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20672876/972128 below and the comments to that answer.

Answer (score 41):

I usually like to have the "model" file as well when I create the join table. Therefore I do.

```
rails g model AssignmentSecurityUser assignments_security:references user:references
```

Answer (score 3):

There's embeded generation for join table in rails

```
rails g migration AddCityWorkerJoinTable cities:uniq workers
```

which generates following migration

```
create_join_table :cities, :workers do |t|
  t.index [:city_id, :worker_id], unique: true
end
```

❗️ NOTE:

- models names should go in alphabet order
- put `:uniq` only on first param

Comment: That note is not entirely accurate; model names do not have to be in alphabetical order. I think you are misreading the [Creating a Join Table](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-join-table) documentation, which states `By default, the name of the join table comes from the union of the first two arguments provided to create_join_table, in alphabetical order. To customize the name of the table, provide a :table_name option`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this would be an updated answer for rails 5

```
create_table :join_table_name do |t|
  t.references :table_name, foreign_key: true
  t.references :other_table_name, foreign_key: true
end
```

Comment: How would you do this for Rails 6? Running `rails g migration CreateJoinTableBookGenre book genre`, for example, creates 2 commented-out lines: first, `t.index [:book_id, :genre_id]`, and 2nd — the same but with `:book_id` and `:genre_id` swapped. I'm confused; should I pick one or uncomment both?

Comment: run `rails g migration AnyNameYouWantToUse`
This will generate a migration file, Add the code inside of `def change` (should be empty). Then run `rails db:migrate`

Comment: Extra points for adding foreign keys. Always leverage DB data integrity features whenever possible!