# how to create a 3 table join migration in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 tables, students messages and coaches.
now i want to create a join migration table with message_id coach_id and student_id

please help to create the migration query

any help is highly appreciated

**getting this error when i tried the below code**

```
== 20150924072052 AssociationTable: migrating
=================================                                                   
-- create_table(:associations)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Key column 'student_id' doesn't exist in table: ALTER TABLE   `associations` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_122f0db022` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`)`
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate migration - create join table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765249/generate-migration-create-join-table)

Comment: @Pavan this is 2 table join migration .but  i need 3 table join, this is not working in case of three

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like this:

```
$ rails g migration AssociationTable
```

... which will create a file such as the following:

```
#db/migrate/association_table_[timestamp].rb
class AssociationTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :associations do |t|
      t.references :student
      t.references :message
      t.references :coache
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This will create a table with the following columns:

```
id
student_id
message_id
coach_id
created_at
updated_at
```

This will be used in a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship, which requires you to have a `join model`:

```
#app/models/association.rb
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
   belongs_to :message
   belongs_to :coach
end
```

--

To update you regarding the choice between `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`, here is what you need to know:

The main difference between the two is the fact that `has_many :through` utilizes a [*join model*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many). Join models are basically a model through which ActiveRecord will populate dependent associative data. In short, it "joins" two models together.

Although the join model is the big difference between [`HABTM`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) and [`HMT`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association), there is another technical reason why you'd choose between them - **`HMT` permits you to have extra attributes in the join model**.

This is important for something like this:

```
#app/models/doctor.rb
class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

#app/models/appointment.rb
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | doctor_id | patient_id | time | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :doctor
   belongs_to :patient
end

#app/models/patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :appointments
   has_many :doctors, through: :appointments
end
```

The join model (appointment) will therefore be able to have specific data that you'll be able to use with the other models:

```
@doctor = Doctor.find 1
@appointments = @doctor.appointments.where(time: ____)
@patients = @appointments.patients
```

Lots of queries. I hope you get the idea.

[image]

--

[`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) is a lot simpler, although I'm not sure if it works for 3 tables (don't see why it shouldn't).

[image]

This removes the need for a join model, and in the process prevents you from being able to use extra attributes in the association (notice how the join *table* has no `id` or `timestamp` attributes?). The naming convention for HABTM tables is `albabetical_plurals` - in your case **`recipient_messages`**

Again, I don't know if this will work for a 3-way join, but here's how you'd do it:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :messages, join_table: "recipients_messages", foreign_key: "recipient_id", association_foreign_key: "message_id"
end

#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipients, join_table: "recipients_messages", foreign_key: "message_id", association_foreign_key: "recipient_id"
end
```

---

Thinking about your request specifically, I'd say that you'd be better with `has_many :through`.

Reason being that if you're sending *messages*, you need a way to know to whom the message was sent, its content and whether it's been read.

I would use `messages` as the join model:

```
#app/models/message.rb
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | student_id | coach_id | message | read | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :student
   belongs_to :coach
end

#app/models/coach.rb
class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
end

#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
end
```

Comment: shows this error     `$ rake db:migrate
== 20150924072052 AssociationTable: migrating =================================
-- create_table(:associations)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Table 'associations' already exists: CREATE TABLE `associations` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb:305:in `query'`

Comment: Have you ran the migration before? You've already got a table called `associations`

Comment: Okay sorry it was my mistake. Let me fix it for you - you'll have to roll back if that's okay

Comment: Okay I updated `foreign_key` to `references`. The foreign key only adds a foreign key; references creates a column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90504/discussion-between-sreena-and-rich-peck).

Comment: Thanks @Rich Pick now i got migration . what is the need of creating association.rb table.is it required here?

Comment: In this instance, yes. If you want to use HABTM, you wouldn't need the model, but you'd need to re-create the table without the `id`. I can write an update if you need

Comment: Sure, let me do that for you!